# single row based on min of one column with a join

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to get the certain columns from a row associated with min(date) by joining with another table.

I am using this in Hive.

My query is:

```
With temp1 as
(Select employee_id as emp_id, min(date) as min_date from employee where        employee_id in (select employee_id from employee_sal) group by employee_id)
Select
employee_sal.dept_code,
Temp1.emp_id,
employee_sal.dept_name,
employee_sal.paid_loc,
employee_sal.country_paid,
min_date
from employee_sal inner join temp1 on employee_sal.employee_id =   emp1.employee_id
```

But I need the dept_name, paid_loc, country_paid based on the min(date) based on employee table like this:

employee_sal.dept_code, Temp1.emp_id, temp1.dept_name, temp1.paid_loc, temp1.country_paid, min_date

These should be the values associated with the min(date) from employee.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I don't see why employee would have a `date` column, with multiple rows per employee.

Answer (score 0):

```
With temp1 as
(Select employee_id as emp_id, min(date) as min_date from employee where employee_id in (select employee_id from employee_sal) group by employee_id)
Select
employee_sal.dept_code,
Temp1.emp_id,
employee_sal.dept_name,
employee_sal.paid_loc,
employee_sal.country_paid,
min_date
from employee_sal inner join temp1 on employee_sal.employee_id = emp1.employee_id And employee_sal.min_date = emp1.min_date
```

Comment: I need employee_sal.dept_code, temp1.emp_id, temp1.dept_name, temp1,paid_loc, temp1.country_paid, temp1.min_date and the date in employee_sal is not equal to min_date. I need the associated row from the temp1 for the min_date except dept_code

Comment: can you please provide some sample data of table ?